# Gcc plugin api from 4.8 to 4.9

Tags: gcc, gcc-plugins

I'm trying to update my plugins from the gcc4.8.3 to the 4.9.1 version
of GCC, the interface seems to have change abit and I don't understand
a few basic things anymore. I didn't find any examples on GCC
documentation about plugins or internet on how to register a pass with
the new interface.
I just want to install a new pass in my plugin, so I'm filling the
structure register_pass_info and pass it to the register_callback this
way :

```
        register_callback("my_plugin_
name", PLUGIN_PASS_MANAGER_SETUP, NULL, &pass_info);
```

I don't understand how to fill the field "pass" of the structure
register_pass_info. It seems now this field is a opt_pass class and
not a simple structure anymore, same class as the internal pass of
GCC. So I naturally tried to copy what the internals pass are doing to
create a new pass, I did this for my pass :

```
class pass_greg : public gimple_opt_pass
{
public:
  pass_greg (gcc::context ctxt)
    : gimple_opt_pass (pass_data_greg, gcc::context ctxt)
  {}

  bool gate () { return greg_gate(); }
  unsigned int execute () { return greg_pass (); }

};
```

but I don't undertand what is this parameter gcc::context that I need
to instantiate my pass. Moreover the opt_pass symbole is defined in
pass_manager which include a "pass-instances.def" that is not in the
plugin API

Maybe some of you have a little example to put me back on track, or
point me to some docs that I missed.

Answer (score 2):

Ha finally found the answer, that was pretty simple in fact : There are some simple examples included in gcc sources files but they are quite hidden =), they are in $(GCC_SRC)/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/plugin/

So I was pretty close from the solution, here is the simpliest code to install a pass

```
#include <gcc-plugin.h>
#include <context.h> //This is is the context g that is needed for the pass constructor


const pass_data pass_data_greg =
{
  GIMPLE_PASS, /* type */
  "Greg's Plugin", /* name */
  OPTGROUP_LOOP, /* optinfo_flags */
  true, /* has_gate */
  true, /* has_execute */
  TV_TREE_PREFETCH, /* tv_id */
  ( PROP_cfg | PROP_ssa ), /* properties_required */
  0, /* properties_provided */
  0, /* properties_destroyed */
  0, /* todo_flags_start */
  0, /* todo_flags_finish */
};

class pass_greg : public gimple_opt_pass
{
public:
  pass_greg (gcc::context ctxt)
    : gimple_opt_pass (pass_data_greg, gcc::context ctxt)
  {}

  bool gate () { return greg_gate(); }
  unsigned int execute () { return greg_pass (); }

int plugin_init(struct plugin_name_args   *info,  /* Argument infor */
                struct plugin_gcc_version *ver)   /* Version of GCC */
{
//... Some version check and so ...
pass.pass = make_pass_greg(g);
    pass.reference_pass_name = "ssa";
    pass.ref_pass_instance_number = 1;
    pass.pos_op = PASS_POS_INSERT_AFTER;

register_callback("rodetect", PLUGIN_PASS_MANAGER_SETUP, NULL, &pass);

};
```

Comment: I will leave that here to complement your answer:
https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2015-05/msg00046.html